# TFS build write message to summary

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I want add a message (link) in the build summary (can be a new section also, doesn't really matter):

[image]

Based on this: https://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2017/04/25/Writing-to-the-Build-Report-in-TFS-2015.aspx,

I've added this line in my Powershell script:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=DotCover Results;]"
```

However I get an error message:

> Unable to process command '##vso[task.addattachment
>   type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=DotCover Results;]'
>   successfully. Please reference documentation
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296) Cannot upload task
>   attachment file, attachment file location is not specified or
>   attachment file not exist on disk

How would one add a text/link/href in the summary of the build? (powershell or other method?)

EDIT:
Please see edit below. I run this script from PowerShell during the build step:

```html
$path = $sourcesFolder + "file:///C:/Temp/dotCover-xunit.html"
Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=DotCover Results;]$path"
```

EDIT 2: (tried a simple text)

```html
function AddSummaryMessage{
 $filePath = "somestring"
 Write-Host "##vso[task.uplaodsummary]$filePath"
}
```

also tried with "hellomessage" as string in there:

Error message:

> 2019-04-27T01:49:01.1513980Z ##[error]Unable to process command
>   '##vso[task.addattachment
>   type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=DotCover Results;]hellomessage'
>   successfully. Please reference documentation
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
>   2019-04-27T01:49:01.1516289Z ##[error]Cannot upload task attachment
>   file, attachment file location is not specified or attachment file not
>   exist on disk

[image]

EDIT 3:

```html
function AddSummaryMessage{
 $file = Get-ChildItem $outputFolder -name "dotcover.html";
 if ($file){
  LogMessage("Found dotcover report file: " + ($outputFolder + $file))
  $path = ($outputFolder + $file)
  Write-Host "##vso[task.uplaodsummary]$path"
 }
}

OUTPUT:

9:27:01 AM  add summary message
9:27:01 AM  Found dotcover report file: C:\Builds\tfsbuilddev02\Agent1\110\s\dotCover\dotcover.html
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like you are missing the message `Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=ObjectSharp;]*$Tempfile*" `

Comment: tried that. didn't work

Comment: I have tried the example you provide and it worked for me. can you please provide more information ? maybe a screenshot of error and the code.

Comment: please see EDIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "hellomessage" can't work because you **must** give a file path and not just a string.

In the attempt with the PowerShell script you have a problem in the file path.

I don't know what the value of the `sourcesFolder` and I can't understand what is the `+ file ...`.

I tried to concatenate the file path in this way:

```
$filePath = $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test.html
# Verify the path is correct:
Write-Host $filePath
# Output: D:\a\1\s\test.html
```

And I upload the file to the Summary page in this way:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.uplaodsummary]$filePath"
```

The upload succeeded and the `test.html` exist in the build summary page.

So in your case you must to check the file path and fix it, after it the upload will work (you can try also put hard coded path and check if it works).

***P.S*** - The `task.uploadsuammry` is a short hand to `task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: Unable to process command '##vso[task.uplaodsummary]C:\Builds\tfsbuilddev03\Agent1\6\s\' successfully. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)
##vso[task.uplaodsummary] is not a recognized command for Task command extension. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817296)

Comment: Did you check the file path is correct? can you print the path variable and share here?

Comment: I tried with a simple text. Just to confirm this should work?: Write-Host "##vso[task.uplaodsummary]test123"

Comment: As I said in the first line of my answer, you can't put a simple text, you must give a file.

Comment: you can't. put simple text in a file (like text.html).

Comment: ok, i have a param that comes in like so: param (
 $sourcesFolder 
), then i would like to use this param: $filePath = $sourcesFolder\test.html. Will this work?

Comment: If the `$sorucesFolder` is like: `c:/folder` and the real location of the file is `c:/folder/test.html` it should work.

Comment: doesn't work. Please see EDIT 3 + images. I've verified dotcover.html file does exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192579/discussion-between-shanekm-and-shayki-abramczyk).

Comment: Works :). Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=DotCover Report;]$path", File has to exist otherwise i was getting error message

Comment: is there anyway to make it a link? so for example now i create txt file and write text there. if i write "<a href='yahoo.com'>click me</a>" i see "click me" shows up correctly but does not work

Comment: website link will work if you will add `target="_blank"`, I see your second question about link to file, try this, maybe it will help also.

Comment: To everyone reading this answer and comment chain, please note that every instance of upLOAD contains a typo upLAOD and it appears that no one noticed it when copypasting.