# TFS write string message to build summary

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to write string message to TFS build summary. I have a Powershell task with variable

```
   $output = $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\scripts\SCRIPT_NAME.ps1

   $output
```

that holds

```
   =====
   Numb. of files for patch in:
   Win32 = 2
   Win64 = 123
   ---
   Numb. of original files:
   Win32 = 0
   Win64 = 12
   =====
```

that scheme is a whole message, now I just want to display it in a place that picture below points or in any other section as long as it is in "Summary"
[image: Like that]
I took a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873998/tfs-build-write-message-to-summary) Stack question but it answers how to display hyperlink to file. I want to specifically display string not a link to file that holds what I want to print. Additionally I referred to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) but I haven't found what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is just using **Logging Commands** as your shared link suggested:

```
##vso[task.uploadsummary]local file path
```

> Upload and attach summary markdown to current timeline record. This
>   summary shall be added to the build/release summary and not available
>   for download with logs.

This **will not generate hyperlink in summary, it will directly list the text/content in the shared file on build Summary page**. You just need to put the output in a file, then use above command lin.

For example:

1. Add PowerShell task

Script:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadsummary]c:\testsummary.md"
```

[image]

---

Besides, you could also create your own extension to display graphical content  in my Azure DevOps build summary page. (Too complicated, not recommend)

For example **add a custom section** in build result through your extension, with this way, you can add html test results report in that custom section.
There is the sample about build result extension: [vsts-extension-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer)

More information about how to build extension, you can refer to this article

[**Create your first extension for Visual Studio Team Services**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node)

A extension for your reference [Publish HTML Artifact](https://github.com/johnwalley/vsts-publish-html-artifact)

---

**Update**

In md files for Markdown format  you could use `</br>` to wrap next line. Start a line with a hash character `#` to set a heading. For example

```
=====</br>Processed files statistics </br>Numb. of files for patch in: Win32 = 2 [this is single line]</br> #Win64 = 123 [this is header] </br>[here split to lines rest of report]</br>=====
```

Then the result format of report you could check right part:

[image]

Comment: How can I format this `*.md` file? For me with report from question I receive `Report.md\n =====\n Processed files statistics\n Numb. of files for patch in: Win32 = 2 [this is single line]\n * Win64 = 123* [this is header]\n [here split to lines rest of report]`

Comment: @Uliysess Azure DevOps/TFS also use the normal format of mark down file. For details you could take a look at this [Syntax guidance for basic Markdown usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops) I also updated my reply with a sample format of your report for your reference. Please kindly check it. Besides, you could also use html report.

Answer (score 0):

### **Partial/temporary solution**

As this is currently closest solution to 100% correctly answer question this is accepted answer. Question will be updated when better solution is implemented and pointed by somebody here

---

As at the moment I need quick solution I display content of `$output` using `task.logissue type=warning`. As just using `Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]$output"` will display content of `$output` in one line I'm splitting it on new line and iterating through array

```
    $output = $output.Split("`n`r")

    foreach($line in $output){ 
            Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]$line" 
    }
```

That produces expected output

**Edit.:** With described solution I'm partially answering my question - I'm displaying **Warning** but I want to display only information. Not marked as Error or Warning

Comment: Instead of type=warning, use type=debug. Like so ```##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]```